# triple integral $\iiint e^{-x^2-y^2-z^2+xy+yz+xz} \,dx\,dy \,dz$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

I need to solve this
triple integral $$\iiint e^{-x^2-y^2-z^2+xy+yz+xz} \,dx\,dy \,dz$$ 
where $V$ is all $\Bbb R^3$

I've spent on this task a few hours,
ok firstly
$$e^{-x^2-y^2-z^2+xy+yz+xz}=e^{-1/2[(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2]}$$

I tried to use theorm of the change of variables, but
this substitution doesn't make sense
$$x-y=a$$
$$y-z=b$$
$$z-x=c$$

also
$$e^{-x^2-y^2-z^2+xy+yz+xz}=e^{(x-1/2y^2-1/2z^2)^2+((\sqrt{3}/2)y-
(\sqrt3/2)z)^2}$$
Maybe here change of variables'll be OK.

Please, help me. It's my homework, so important and I have no idea what I should do next.

Comment: Why should $a=x-y$, $b=y-z$ and $c=x-z$ make no sense?

Comment: Maybe you can try with

$$-x^2-y^2-z^2 + xy + xz + yz = -(x + y + z)^2 + 3(xy + xz + yx)$$

And then use spherical polar coordinates?

Comment: What sort of course are you taking in which this is showing up as homework? The fact that your attempted change of variables "makes no sense" should actually be a hint to what's going on here.

Comment: @Peter define x,y,z by new variables

Comment: @TedShifrin mathematical analysis 2.2 [University of Warsaw]

Comment: @MartaCzerwonka Is the result $\infty$?

Comment: So your attempted change of variables doesn't work. Why? How can you nevertheless use this approach (with a different third variable, perhaps) and see what's going on?

Comment: @Peter: Note that $g(x,y,z) = (x-y,y-z,z-x)$ is *not* an invertible linear map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can do it with simple calculus, in addition to what has already been written, to clarify things. Starting with using Fubini's lemma to "separate" the integrals order.
I will also use this notation:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} = \int$$

For the sake of simplicity.

$$\iiint e^{-x^2 - y^2 - z^2 + xy + xz + zy}\ \text{d}x\ \text{d}y\ \text{d}z = \int e^{-x^2}\ \text{d}x \int e^{-y^2 + xy}\ \text{d}y \int e^{-z^2 - z(x+y)}\ \text{d}z$$

Now we use an important result from elementary calculus which states

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-ax^2 + bx}\ \text{d}x = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} e^{b^2/4a}$$

Thence applying that to our integral (with $a = 1$ and $b = x+y$) we get:

$$\iiint e^{-x^2 - y^2 - z^2 + xy + xz + zy}\ \text{d}x\ \text{d}y\ \text{d}z = \int e^{-x^2}\ \text{d}x \int e^{-y^2 + xy}\ \text{d}y \left(\sqrt{\pi} e^{(x+y)^2/4}\right)$$

Arranging and we have

$$\sqrt{\pi}\int e^{-x^2 + x^2/4}\ \text{d}x \int e^{-y^2 + xy + y^2/4 + xy/2}\ \text{d}y$$

Using the same procedure we get:

$$\sqrt{\pi}\int e^{-x^2 + x^2/4} \left(2 e^{3x^2/4 + 3xy/2}\right)\ \text{d}x$$

namely

$$2\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\int e^{-3x^2/4 + 3x^2/4}\ \text{d}x = 2\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} 1 \text{d}x = \infty$$

Thence it does not converge.

Comment: I am so very grateful! Thank you very much! beautiful solution<3

Answer (score 8):

Since:
$$ \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} \exp\left[-\left(a^2 x^2+b^2 y^2+c^2 z^2\right)\right]\,d\mu = \frac{\pi^{3/2}}{|abc|}$$
by Fubini's theorem, in order to compute our integral it is enough to find the product of the eigenvalues of the matrix associated with the quadratic form $q(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz$, i.e.
$$ \det\begin{pmatrix}1 & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{1}{2} & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 1\end{pmatrix}=\color{red}{0} $$
to be able to state that the original integral $\color{red}{\text{is not}}$ converging.

In the general case, if $q(x,y,z)$ is a positive definite quadratic form associated with a matrix $A_q$,
$$ \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\exp\left[-q(x,y,z)\right]\,d\mu = \sqrt{\frac{\pi^3}{\det A_q}}.$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your solution.:(

Comment: @MartaCzerwonka: if we assume that the integral exists, its value is the same if we apply a change of variable given by an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^3$. If we take the isometry that brings the quadratic form into its diagonal form, we may check that the integral just depends on the product of the diagonal elements, i.e. on the determinant of the symmetric matrix associated with our quadratic form.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution!! *_* But I'm afraid the OP is still "young" or maybe she took a more elementary calculus class..?

Answer (score 2):

To pursue the change-of-variables method further, note that with $a$ and $b$ defined as originally done, we have
$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy - xz - yz = \frac{1}{2} \left[ (x - y)^2 + (y - z)^2 + (z - x)^2 \right] = \frac{1}{2} \left[ a^2 + b^2 + (a + b)^2 \right],
$$
since $a + b = x - z$.  Rearranging, we then get
$$
\frac{1}{2} \left[ a^2 + b^2 + (a + b)^2 \right] = \frac{1}{4} \left[ 3 (a + b)^2 + (a - b)^2 \right],
$$
since $a^2 + b^2 = \frac{1}{2}(a + b)^2 + \frac{1}{2}(a - b)^2$.  We can therefore use a different set of coordinates:
$$
u = a + b = x - z, \qquad v = a - b = x - 2y + z, \qquad w = z
$$
(Really, $w$ can be pretty much anything—see below.)  The integral then becomes, up to an overall constant coming from the Jacobian,
$$
\iiint e^{-\frac{3}{4}u^2 - \frac{1}{4} v^2} \, du \, dv\, dw.
$$
Since there is no $w$-dependence in the integrand, and since its range of integration will run from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, we conclude that the integral does not converge.

The dummy coordinate $w$, by the way, can be chosen to be any coordinate that linearly dependent on $x, y, z$ and that is not degenerate with $u$ and $v$ (i.e., one that doesn't cause the Jacobian matrix to have zero determinant, which basically means something that is not a linear combination of $u$ and $v$.)